# How to extract line after line with matching pattern in perl

Tags: perl

I am new in perl. I am trying this code below to extract line after the line that has string "length' in my text file `merge.txt`. I want to get the result as shown below. can someone please help me with what I need to add to my code. Thanks

```
my @array;    

While (@array = ‘/Users/Desktop/merged.txt’) {    

  foreach my $line (@array) {    

    if ($line =~ m/length/) {      

      my $a = $array[$i+1];    
      push (@array, $a);    
    }  

    my $wanted_type = "$1";      
    print "$wanted_type\n";      
  }      
}    
}
```

`merge.txt` file has

```
owner@owner-HP-Z840-Workstation ~/SLM/Desktop/Documents
 % ./count-smRNAs.pl /media/owner/c92ed9e9-3d94-497c-bb2e-514a4806bbcd/merged.fastq 32 32
length  number  A   C   G   T
32  14824945    1992856 1576607 2413263 8756583
owner@owner-HP-Z840-Workstation ~/SLM/Desktop/Documents
 % ./count-smRNAs.pl /media/owner/c92ed9e9-3d94-497c-bb2e-514a4806bbcd/merged.fastq 33 33
length  number  A   C   G   T
33  58619575    1415093 3274505 5499169 48070172
owner@owner-HP-Z840-Workstation ~/SLM/Desktop/Documents
 % ./count-smRNAs.pl /media/owner/c92ed9e9-3d94-497c-bb2e-514a4806bbcd/test.fastq 34 34
length  number  A   C   G   T
34  13018196    1047476 903554  1695778 9296236
```

result I want is shown below. I also want to grab the filename from line 
 that has `/c92ed9e9-3d94-497c-bb2e-514a4806bbcd/` as shown below.

```
merged.fastq
32  14824945    1992856 1576607 2413263 8756583
33  58619575    1415093 3274505 5499169 48070172
test.fastq
34  13018196    1047476 903554  1695778 9296236
```

Comment: Please have the courtesy to lay out your code sensibly when you are asking for free assistance to fix it.

Comment: I have added indentation to your code. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in future. If you are asking a large group of strangers to read and understand your code, then it is surely only polite to make it as easy to follow as possible. My indentation appears to have revealed an extra `}`. I've left it there, but you might want to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $print;
while (<>) {
   if ( my $qfn = /^\s*%\s*\S+\s+(\S+)/ ) {
      ( my $fn = $qfn ) =~ s{^.*/}{}s;
      print("$fn\n");
   }

   print if $print;
   $print = /length/;
}
```

Comment: Why am I getting this error: `Unrecognized character \xE2; marked by <-- HERE after while (<-- HERE near column 8 at perl_test.pl line 2.`

Comment: @MAPK, You miscopied my code. There is no such character in my program.

Comment: Then you miscopied it again. In my program, the character after `while (` is `<` (`3C`), not nonsense (`E2`).

Comment: Ok, IS it not how your direct your file? `while ('/Users/Desktop/merged.txt') {`

Comment: No. `while ('/Users/Desktop/merged.txt')` is the same as `while (1)`, an infinite loop. Keep `while (<>)` and pass the path as an argument on the command line. (Alternatively, you'll need to use `open`.)

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: hum? It's quite basic. Not only that, since you already know what the whole does, you should have no problem figuring out what each bit does! What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: By the way, judging from the lines numbers in your earlier error message, it looks like you didn't add `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`. ALWAYS use these. (It's common to not include them in snippets since it's presumed everyone knows to use them.)